# field initializer is not constant g++ 4.8.4

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I tried to compile the following code on my laptop, using g++ 4.8.4:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <tuple>

struct Storage {
  static const int num_spatial_subset = 8;
  static constexpr std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> vectors{ {0,0,0}, 
      {0,1,0}, 
      {0,0,1}, 
      {1,1,0}, 
      {1,0,1}, 
      {0,1,1}, 
      {1,0,0}, 
      {1,1,1} };
  double storage[num_spatial_subset][vectors.size()];
};


int main()
{
}
```

And I got this error message:

```
error: field initializer is not constant
constexpr std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<double> > vectors{ {0,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,1}, {1,1,0}, {1,0,1}, {0,1,1}, {1,0,0}, {1,1,1} };
```

However, I copy/paste the same code on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe9e89907ae1faa2) (g++ 6.1.0), with the same compilation parameters and it worked.

Can someone tells me what is wrong please ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think C++11 support in `gcc 4.8.4` is still experimental, if you upgrade to `gcc 4.9` I think it should have a better chance of working.

Comment: Given that it works on modern compilers, I would not put any money on the old version being correct. If you need to support "ancient" compilers, don't get fancy with modern language features.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as pointed out by Chris and Baum, updating to g++ 4.9 fixed it.