# C++11 - Can't define constexpr literal using constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constexpr

I've run into what seems a counterintuitive error, namely, the inability to assign the value of a `constexpr` function to a `constexpr` literal (hope I'm using the language right).  Here's the example:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  static constexpr int FooValue(int n) { return n + 5; }
  static constexpr int Foo5 = FooValue(5);  // compiler error
  static constexpr int Foo5Alt(void) { return FooValue(5); }  // OK
};
```

In GCC 4.8.4, `Foo5` is flagged for `field initializer is not constant`.  Found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758382/field-initializer-is-not-constant-g-4-8-4) suggesting that the older version of GCC might be the culprit.  So I plugged it into [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d566a0854e3c572) (GCC 6.2.0) and got the error `'static constexpr int MyClass::FooValue(int)' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete`.  I added `Foo5Alt()` which returns its value as a `constexpr` function rather than literal, and that compiles fine.

I guess I'm not following why `FooValue(5)` can't be used as the initializer for `Foo5`.  The definition for `FooValue(int n)` is complete, isn't it?  `{ return n + 5; }` is the entire definition.  `constexpr` denotes an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time, so why can it not be used to define the return value of a `constexpr` literal?

What subtlety of C++ am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, inline definitions of member functions for a class are only parsed after the declaration of the class is complete.

So even though the compiler "knows" about `MyClass::FooValue(int)`, it hasn't "seen" its definition yet, and hence it can't be used in a `constexpr` expression.

A general workaround for this is to stick to `constexpr` member functions, or declare `constexpr` constants outside the class.

Answer (score 4):

According to the standard, `MyClass` is considered an incomplete type when you try to invoke `FooValue` to initialize `Foo5`. Therefore, you cannot use its members as you did.
The type is considered *a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}`*.
On the other side, *the class is regarded as complete within function bodies*. That's why `Foo5Alt` compiles just fine.
See [[class.mem]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-6) for further details.